# delete a system attribute in magento which is no longer in database

Tags: attributes, magento-1.9, eav

I know i can go to eav_attribute and make it user defined and delete it, but its not there ..

This was created by an extension, which i have uninstalled and now the attribute is throwing errors something like

```
a:5:{i:0;s:76:"Source model "marketplace/source_option" not found for attribute "seller_id"";i:1;s:3374:"#0 
/mysite/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')
```

i can see still see `seller_id` attribute in backend, however it is system attribute and i just want to get rid of it.
Now its nowhere in eav_attribute :-(

P.S: This was a magento marketplace plugin www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/super-simple-multi-vendor-marketplace-free.html

Comment: Strange. How can it be in the backend but not in the eav_attribute table? Are tou sure you looked for the right thing. You can try a different approach. Search the `eav_attribute` table for records with `source_model` = 'marketplace/source_option'.

Comment: yes that was my first reaction strange!!

Comment: @Marius i found it, by source_model :-) thank you, such a silly thing i just looked over

Comment: I wrote this as an answer so this question will not remain "orphan".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All attributes that appear in the backend must be in the table `eav_attribute`.
If you cannot find the attribute by code for some reason, you can try to find it by source model. After all, if one attribute has a non valid source model, all the attributes with that source model should be deleted.

```
Select * From eav_attribute where source_model = 'marketplace/source_option'
```